# my archive build fails with error "no such module combine"

Tags: xcode

I recently added some Combine Code to my project (storyboard project), which run successfully on device and simulator.
Unfortunately if i try to build my archive file i got "no such module combine" error.

I searched long time via google and stackoverflow, but nothing helped. Anybody an idea?

find out, that it works for deployment target 11.0 and 12.0 and 13.0, just 10.0 says: no such module Combine

Answer (score 3):

I faced same trouble yesterday - a huge set of errors under RELEASE environment:

- "use of undeclared type 'View'";
- "no such module 'Combine'";
- some other declarations from SwiftUI are also not recognisable;

In same time everything is fine under DEBUG environment.

The problem was in supporting iOS9+ and using SwiftUI for iOS13+ in same time.
It is probably a bug in Xcode (11.3.1, 11.5 are checked), but YES, we have 2 options here:

1. we have to increase deployment target up to iOS11+;
2. we can stay deployment target iOS9+, but we have to wrap any SwiftUI files in preprocessor directives like this:

> ```
> import SwiftUI
>
> #if canImport(Combine)
>  ... any SwiftUI code here ...
> #endif
> ```

I choose the second option because we still need to support such an old version as iOS9.

Comment: By the way: #if canImport(SwiftUI)  does not work
it is not a mistake - you must use #if canImport(Combine)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the platform in the package description.
Make sure you are opening `xcworkspace` instead of `xcodeproj`

If this does not help, go to **build settings** and defining the **Framework Search Paths** to a folder which contains the frameworks in question.
If the frameworks are placed in your project directory, just set the framework search path to `$(SRCROOT)` and set it to recursive.

Comment: the framework is Combine...Apples Framework...and i am not using package description at all...do i have to?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with archiving Parchment swift package.
So, I moved Parchment from spm to cocoapod and it archives successfully.